# Objective C: Passing NSDictionary from One Class to Another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

All,

*Disclaimer: I'm aware that there are other questions that ask similar questions, but none provide an answer that I understand or an answer that applies to my situation.*

I have two classes, classA and classB. In classA there is a void instance method that creates a NSMutableDictionary (if you want specifics, it's a XMLparser). After classA's XMLParser is run and the NSMutableDictionary has been created and filled, classB is called which needs to do some other things with that dictionary. For some reason, classB cannot access the NSMutableDictionary in classA (actually, it can access it, but for some reason it shows up as "NULL"). What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: You asked for the source code, you got it. ClassA below, dictionary in question is called "response."**

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "CardSetupViewController.h"

@implementation XMLParser

@synthesize response;

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser
{
    self = [super init];
    // init dictionary of response data 
    response = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    return self;
}

//Gets Start Element of SessionData
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
        didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
        namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
        qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"SessionData"]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Found SessionData in the return XML! Continuing...");
        //response is a NSMutableArray instance variable

        //THIS SHOULD NEVER NEED TO BE USED
            if (!response)//if array is empty, it makes it!
            {
                NSLog(@"Dictionary is empty for some reason, creating...");
            response = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            }
        //END: THIS SHOULD NEVER BE USED
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        currentElementName = elementName;
        NSLog(@"Current Element Name = %@", currentElementName);
        return;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
    if (!currentElementValue) {
        // init the ad hoc string with the value     
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    } else {
        [currentElementValue setString:string];
        NSLog(@"Processing value for : %@", string);
    }
}  

//Gets End Element of SessionData
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"SessionData"]) 
    {
        // We reached the end of the XML document
        // dumps dictionary into log
        NSLog(@"Dump:%@", [response description]);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //Adds key and object to dictionary
        [response setObject:currentElementValue forKey:currentElementName];
        NSLog(@"Set values, going around again... brb.");
    }
    currentElementValue = nil;
    currentElementName = nil;
}


@end
```

Comment: I believe you can get better help if you post the source code related to your problem

Comment: I have attached the source code. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure classA isn't released or releases your dictionary before you try to do stuff with it on B. Also, any threading involved?

Comment: As a side note, your initializer does not follow the conventions. Its return type should be `id` as described in [Implementing an Initializer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW1). It should also check `if (self)`, as discussed in [Handling Initialization Failure](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13)

Comment: What about the code where you create this instance of ClassA, then create the instance of ClassB, and then pass this response from one to the other? Isn't that where you're having the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look into using singletons.

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

http://pixeleap.com/?p=19

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5302-how-make-global-variables-objectivec.html

Those should get you started, if you need clarification just ask.

Comment: Singletons took care of me. Thank you so much. 

btw: for those looking here for future reference, check this link as well in addition to those (it was the four combined that really gave me a good understanding). http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32

Answer (score 0):

Are `currentElementName` and `currentElementValue` ivars ? If so, every time you catch either an element or a value, you must then release your ivar and retain the new value you catch.

Also, as the comments are saying you didn't follow any rules about writing a correct initializer.

What about `classB` ? Isn't there some logic that makes your dictionary be released ?
Try managing a bit more the memory.

Comment: Using ARC. Not going to go into ARC because of NDA, but memory management should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

you have several options... so many options actually

**Option A:(set)**

```
@interface ClassB{
NSDictionary * someDict;
}
-(void)setSomeDict:(NSDictionary *)aDict;
@end

@implementation ClassB
-(void)setSomeDict:(NSDictionary *)aDict
{
   someDict = [aDict retain];//or copy depending on your needs;
}

@end

somewhere in ClassA...

ClassB * b = [ClassB new];
[b setSomeDict: someOtherDict];
```

**Option B:(push)**

```
@interface ClassB{
NSDictionary * someDict;
}
-(void)doSomethingWithDict:(NSDictionary *)aDict;
@end

@implementation ClassB
-(void)doSomethingWithDict:(NSDictionary *)aDict
{
   NSLog(@"did something with aDict: %@",aDict);
}

@end

somewhere in ClassA...

ClassB * b = [ClassB new];
[b doSomethingWithDict: someOtherDict];
```

**Option c:(init)**

```
@interface ClassB{
NSDictionary * someDict;
}
-(id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)aDict;
@end

@implementation ClassB
-(id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)aDict
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self)
   {
        someDict = [someDict retain]; //or copy depending on your needs
   }
   NSLog(@"did something with aDict: %@",aDict);
}

@end

somewhere in ClassA...

ClassB * b = [[ClassB alloc] initWithDict:someOtherDict];
[b doSomethingelse];
```

you can also use properties etc... there are many many options, but you should understand object ownership as well so you don't end up leaking the dictionary.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [someDict release];
}
```

should be added to the classB.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if u get the response in this delegate method of NSXMLParser

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser;
```

and send the response via a delegate (which u should implement in this class) and the delegate method is to implemented in the other class ...Simple !!!